# Play video with this audio in AVMutableCompositionTrack

Tags: audio, video, avmutablecomposition

I have a 2 AVMutableCompositionTrack objects. 1st contains video (with his sound) and 2nd contains some audio, for example mp3. I want to play both of them simultaneously. Everything is OK with the sound of second object. Unfortunately I can't hear the sound of video. Why ?

I can play above mentioned track in the different players. In this case everything is OK. But it is needed to play both items in the same player by using AVMutableCompositionTrack mechanizm (for exporting feature).